# Effective ViewBag using in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, http-verbs

I need to use same ViewBag objects for both HttpVerb these are HttpGet and HttpPost.Therefore I don't want to declare the ViewBags twice.I have created a parametric method and I am calling this method whenever I want to use it as followed sample.Is true way or do you have any solution about that issue?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SetViewObjects(null);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person model)
{
    SetViewObjects(model.PersonId);
    return View(model);
}

public void SetViewObjects(short? personId)
{
    IEnumerable<Person> person = null;

    if(personId.HasValue)
    {
        person = db.GetPerson().Where(m=>m.PersonId == personId);
    }
    else
    {
        person = db.GetPerson();
    }

    ViewBag.Person = person;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `this.SetViewObjects`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.SetViewObjects(null);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person model)
{
    this.SetViewObjects(model.PersonId);
    return View(model);
}
```

Just make it an extension method of ControllerBase e.g.

```
public static void ControllerExt
{
    public static void SetViewObjects(this ControllerBase controller,short? personId)
    {
     IEnumerable<Person> person = null;

    if(personId.HasValue)
    {
        person = db.GetPerson().Where(m=>m.PersonId == personId);
    }
    else
    {
        person = db.GetPerson();
    }

      controller.ViewBag.Person = person;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seem useful.All right i want to ask a question?is true using pluratily viewbag inside a method?

Answer (score 2):

Viewbag is asigned dynamically. you dont need to declare in your HttpGet Action. 
You can use ViewBag.Person in your HttpGet Index view without declaring it in the corresponding action.
 Its value will be null.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for reply.If i do not declare ViewBag inside what i called page , thrown exception.Thus i used viewbag inside a method instead of use twice.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by saying you need to use the same ViewBag objects? Every time your SetViewObjects function is invoked it creates a new ViewBag object.

If you need to use ViewBag to pass collections of data I suggest simply the following(which is still not the best way):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Person = db.GetPerson();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(User model)
    {
        ViewBag.Person = db.GetPerson().Where(m => m.PersonId == model.PersonId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

The overloaded Index function though doesn't make much sense to me - you get a User model from a form Post and then find in the database a user with the same id - which is likely to be the same user as the one you received from view, and then you pass two model classes to the same view but in different ways. Anyway, ideally I'd use the following appr:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.GetPerson());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(User model)
    {
        return View(db.GetPerson().Where(m => m.PersonId == model.PersonId));
    }
```